# how to obtain the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=1$ here...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the following values of X and Y

[image]

I know here we are required to find the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ using numerical methods..

But I am not getting how to use here... Actaully I am not getting the question also...what $x$ and $y$ values are given here..

Please hint me how to deal with this problem..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is there not some missing context?

Comment: no this the same question as it is I have pasted...are you getting any idea of what this table about...

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}$ essentiallly means

> how much does why change when $x$ increases by $1$?

So you can consider portion of the function between $X=0$ and $X=2$. Where $Y$ increases by $7.7815-6.9897=0.7918$. This happens as $X$ increases by $2$. So as $X$ increases by $1$, the change is $Y$ would be approximately;
$\frac{7.7815-6.9897}{2}=\frac{0.7918}{2}=0.3959.$

So this is very close to $A$, and that is the correct answer.

Comment: can you explain me the table I am not getting....what $x$ and $y$ values

Comment: @mathstudent The table gives you the values of a function $y(x)$ for a few discrete $x\,.$ BTW I do not find $0.3959$ being the correct choice when A says $0.395\color{red}0\,.$ But in that case nothing will get any better.

Comment: Can't I consider the region from $x=0$ to $x=1$, i.e. when  $x$ increases by 1, $y$ changes from 6.9897 to 7.4036 and hence option the difference...why considering from 0 to 2

Comment: @mathstudent . If the table is what it is there is no correct value for $dy/dx\,.$ Numerical differentiation is not a science it is an art.

Answer (score 1):

Ploting this,

[image]

That the data is nearly linear. $m=0.338825$.

Or,

[image]

Where, $y=ax^2+bx+c$

Parameters:
$$a =- 0.013225\\
b = 0.418175\\
c = 6.9940285714286$$

$\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=1}=2a+b=4.1553$

Comment: Your decimal dot jumped one place in the result.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps to know

The nearest polynomial using approximation website yields

$$y=-2.9166666666302\cdot10^{-6}x^{6}+0.0000679167x^{5}-0.000660417x^{4}+0.00397708x^{3}-0.0277367x^{2}+0.441255x+6.9867$$

Here is the desmos link
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/htwlh6yj2w

Hence, The slope $y'(1)\approx0.3954$

Approximation website used:https://www.dcode.fr/function-equation-finder

Also note this can also be obtained by using a six degree polynomial curve(why six degree,Because we are given 7 constraints,And six degree polynomial has 7 independant variables)

$$f(x)=ax^6+bx^5+cx^4+dx^3+ex^2+hx+g$$

You have 7 constraints(given co-ordinate table) and 7 variables, Hence solving 7 linear equations will give you the approximate function

Answer (score 0):

In finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$, the rate of change of the y value near $x=1$, we can look at simpler forms and analogies. A simpler form could be $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=1$ for $y$ values $0,1,2,3,4,5$. Simplifying can be useful in problem solving.

Analogies help with creating a mental image of $\frac{dy}{dx}$. In showing a car's speed at a certain point in time, if $x=1$ is one second on the $x$ axis, then the change of the distance, or $y$ value, near $x=1$ means the speed of the car shown on the speedometer. In another analogy, if $x$ values signify horizontal distance and $y$ values are height, then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=1$ is a hill's steepness at $x=1$. The growth rate of a population, and the change in temperature at a certain point in time can also be expressed with $\frac{dy}{dx}$. With analogies we can get a more concrete understanding of what the abstract symbols mean.

On this drawing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the slope of the straight line that touches the curve at $x=1$:
[image]

Another approach I tried in solving this task is approximating the values:

[image]

Watch this video explanation of 3b1b - [The Essence of Calculus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUvTyaaNkzM&list=RDCMUCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw&index=1), it will help in visualising the concept of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.